# Did something change in the calculation of Helpful Flags?

Tags: support, bug, status-bydesign, flags, user-profile

The count of Helpful Flags on my profile has jumped up by several dozen since this morning, but I haven't flagged anything in the interim.

Did something change in how this is calculated? Is something broken?

Comment: http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/185889/13992

Comment: [status-resolved]

Answer (score 4):

Per Jarrod Dixon, [something did change.](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/185866/flag-count-is-missing-from-profile-pages/185889?noredirect=1#comment570008_185889)

> @LessPop_MoreFizz it's by-design. Comment flags weren't being counted correctly.

Mystery Solved.

<sub>I've flagged a lot of comments, huh?</sub>